# Is Y a pronoun or part of a presentatif in this example sentence?

Tags: pronoms

The unit of a grammar book I am using which focuses on the pronoun **Y** contains this example sentence: *Il n'**y** en a plus.* It is listed together with *Il n'**y** va pas.* and *Je ne m'**y** intéresse pas.* and according to the unit it illustrates the formation of negations with the pronoun **Y**. The last two sentences are pretty clear, but the first one seems to contain no pronoun **Y**. Since I don't consider myself advanced enough to doubt the information in the textbook I would be grateful if somebody can help me dispel my doubts. Does the sentence *Il n'**y** en a plus.* contain the pronoun Y? Or is **Y** part of the presentatif **Il y a** in this case?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove the *y* from *il n'y en a* while keeping the meaning because the pronoun *il* can't be impersonal in *il n'en a plus*:

- Il n'y va pas = Il ne va pas **là**
- Je ne m'y intéresse pas = Je ne m'intéresse pas **à ça**
- Il n'y en a plus = Il n'y a plus **de ça** ≠ <s>Il n'a plus de ça ici</s>.

Comment: then what about *Il n'y a rien*? *y* is a location here, isn't it? It can't be the object since the object is *rien*

Comment: @TeleportingGoat If one insist identifying a role for *y*, that might be some kind of subject: "***Ici** n'a plus de ça*" (**There** "has" no more of it).